# comparing 2 monthly libraries if customer No longer exist in following monthl

Tags: sas

How can compare 2 libraries (e.g May vs April) to see  if a customer ID does not longer exist in the following month.  Any SAS code to do this comparison ?

Comment: Have you tried anything, such as `select id from april except select id from may`

Comment: PROC COMPARE is one option, but using a basic SQL or data step is easier.

Comment: Did you mean to say Libraries Or datasets?  Do you just want to compare two datasets or compare multiple datasets?  Either way what output do you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can start with `PROC COMPARE` and look at the output which contains the difference records. You do need a unique way to identify records to identify which ones are new. I personally find `PROC COMPARE` lacking and use `SQL` or `MERGE` to identify records.

`IN` allows you to identify where a record originates. It creates a dummy variables to indicate the source, _apr indicates a record present in April and _may indicates a record present in May.

This will split your data into data sets that have just your April ID, just your May ID and then the data in both. It should get you started.

```
data data_april data_may data_both;
Merge April (KEEP = ID IN = _apr)
      May   (KEEP = ID IN = _may);
by ID;
April = _apr;
May = _may;

*In just April data;
if April and not May then output data_april;


*In just May data;
if not April and May then output data_may;

*In both data sets;
if April & May then output data_both;

run;
```

See the [merge section](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=n1i8w2bwu1fn5kn1gpxj18xttbb0.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#n01jepaobjvwmyn1kd3bghrqo707) and the [combine data section](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=n1tgk0uanvisvon1r26lc036k0w7.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) of the documentation for more details.